# Spring web application giving 404 error on tomcat-7.0.37

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlets

I have made spring web application sample project. I did all the basic configuration, with java based config and servlet 3.0 web.xml.
But after all these configurations when i hit the url it gives me 404 error.
What could be the problem. Could anyone please help me?

web.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee;
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <display-name>SpringPracs</display-name>
    <!-- <welcome-file-list> -->
    <!-- <welcome-file>/jspfiles/index.jsp</welcome-file> -->
    <!-- </welcome-file-list> -->

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>home</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
            <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>home.practise.configuration.SpringConfigs</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>home</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/practise/*</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>

    </servlet>
</web-app>
```

configuration java class:

```
package home.practise.configuration;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "home.practise.application")
@EnableWebMvc
@PropertySource("classpath:practise.properties")
public class SpringConfigs {
    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver internalResourceViewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        internalResourceViewResolver.setPrefix("/jspfiles/");
        internalResourceViewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return internalResourceViewResolver;
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
package home.practise.application;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("homeController")
public class HomeController {
    @RequestMapping("homePage.ht")
    public ModelAndView takeMeToHomePage(){
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("index");
        return modelAndView;
    }
}
```

When I try to access this url

```
http://localhost:8080/SpringPracs/practise/homeController/homePage.ht
```

It gives me 404 error. Though when I access jsp page directly, it shows that page.

Comment: i tried that too.. still its not working. What else could it be?

Comment: Turn your debug logs on and check what the server/Spring has to say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First your use relative URLs when all examples in Spring Reference Manual use *absolute* URLs starting with `/`. I thing it could work, but do yourself a favour and follow Spring examples ...

But the actual problem is that you mapped Spring `DispatcherServlet` to `/practise/*`. It is perfectly correct, but then the you must also declare your controller to respond to `/practise/...` :

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/practise/homeController")
public class HomeController {
    @RequestMapping("/homePage.ht")
    public ModelAndView takeMeToHomePage(){
    ...
    }
}
```

Edit :

As an alternative, you can map controller to `/homeController` and map dispatcher servlet to `/`

Comment: @user3407459 Then I think that you should follow Sotirios's advise and show exactly what is in tomcat logs

Comment: logs showing " Mapped "{[/homeController/homePage.ht],m"

Comment: Mapped "{[/homeController/homePage.ht],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView home.practise.application.HomeController.takeMeToHomePage()

Comment: @user3407459 Should not be that - did you really re-build and re-deploy the application ?

Comment: I cannot understand how you get `Mapped "{[/homeController/homePage.ht],` with `@RequestMapping("/practise/homeController")`. At least should be `Mapped "{[/practise/homeController/homePage.ht],`. Please try to clean and build ...

Comment: after you suggested solution in your answer, i tried that and did not work. So i changed the url-pattern to "/" and removed "practise" from home controller. That's why it is showing this path "/homeController/homePage.ht". But still not working. What could be the problem?

Comment: let me add 1 more info here, i am using spring 4.0. But i guess that should not be the problem. right?

Comment: I have jus added spring-webmvc dependency in my pom. as it includes spring- context, spring-core, spring-web etc. all the required dependencies.

Comment: sorry, i meant i have only added spring-webmvc dependency since beginning. And i dont see error in server logs. Correct me if i am wrong, i am seeing logs at the location where sts deploys tomcat application somewhere in tmp folder which resides in sts folder.

Comment: You should make an edit to your post stating exactely : where is mapped the servlet, how is mapped the controller, the request you type in browser, the error message (and where you read the error message)

Comment: Done. Working fine now. btw , Thanx for the suggestions .  :)